# Scrollspy not working when color adjusted in CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I'm working on a website using bootstrap 4 v6 and am attempting to use scrollspy with a navbar.  For the most part it is working.  I have some JQuery code to change the background of the navbar from transparent to white when scrolling down.  The CSS also changes the color of the text from white on the top, to black once the navbar background is white.  Scrollspy works once the text is black, but when it is white, it is not working.

I've tracked it down to this CSS:

```
/* If removed, scrollspy works.  If !important is removed, scrollspy works,
   but the menu items are black and only the brand is white */
.navbar.notscrolled .navbar-brand,
.navbar.notscrolled a {
    color: white!important;
}
```

This is needed to change the text to white.  If I remove the !important, the text turns black and scrollspy works, but I need the text to be white at this point.

I've included the entire project in jsbin at:

http://jsbin.com/kazixefixi/edit?html,css,js,output

Any idea how I might fix this?